# polymer: can I animate template-if?

Tags: polymer

In my element's DOM I have a template:

```
<template if="{{alert}}">
  <div>hello world</div>
</template>
```

inside the component's code, when `this.alert` is changed and the template gets rendered or removed, I would like to apply a CSS transition to its contents. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could listen for changes to alert in Javascript and handle your css stuff there

```
<div id="hello">hello world</div>

alertChanged: function() {
  this.$.hello.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: `template if` is removing its content from the DOM, isn't it?

Comment: That makes it quite hard to animate. Binding `opacity` to `alert` instead of using `template if` would make it easy to animate.

Comment: what you are saying is remove it from the template and let the alertChanged function do all the work?

Comment: Yes I think you need to remove `<template if>` entirely. What's the point of animating properties of an element that was already removed from the DOM ;-) Instead of `alertChanged` you could use https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#styleobject (see also https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/270)

Comment: i see what you are getting at. i was thinking more about animating when alert as added not thinking the same function would give error about style.opacity of null when {{alert}} is removed. updating my answer to remove if template. i am not sure how to apply the styleObject method here as i have never used it. maybe you can elaborate and leave another answer.